# SOAP Response with Thai Characters

Tags: java, web-services, soap, character-encoding, thai

How can I have a SOAP Response with Thai Characters?

In datasource, it is written as Thai characters but what i get from SOAP Response, are different set of symbols, i think it's an ASCII or something but not a thai characters.

Comment: How are you creating and sending SOAP requests? Can you give any code to show us what you've got so far?

Comment: What character set have you defined for the xml and the response? The first one can be important for the application that is using your webservice. The second one is how your browser is going to interpret and render the response.

Comment: it is both UTF-8 for the character set

Answer (score 0):

- Check to see if the `Content-Type` header is set correctly in the response message. It should contain `charset=utf-8`.
- Check to see if the xml header of the soap WSDL has the following format `<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>`
- There could also be a mismatch between characters encoding. Check the encoding in the database and the encoding of the returned message and see if they are the same.

Comment: Sir, im using charset utf-8 for content type and wsdl

Comment: and in what encoding are the characters stored in the datasource (database)?